# Nivo Slider CSS Positioning Issue

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

hoping someone may be able to help here; i've got what appears to be a css glitch on my nivo slider. Each slide is dropping about 20px below where it should appear. See what i mean here; http://whatscooking.goodstuffdesign.co.uk

Any help, is hugely appreciated.

Matt

Comment: Where is the CSS for the Nivo Slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included the Nivo Slider CSS file on your page.